DesignTime only information on custom/user-control in c#
I am creating a usercontrol and I want to provide some designtime only debug information directly on the control. I thought about overriding OnPaint but it does not work...
This is what I've tried:
public UserControl1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    m_mode = LicenseManager.UsageMode;
}

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);

    e.Graphics.DrawString(m_mode.ToString(), Font, Brushes.Blue, 5, 5);

    var msg = string.Empty;
    if (m_mode == LicenseUsageMode.Designtime)
    {
        msg = "test";
        e.Graphics.DrawString(msg, Font, Brushes.Red, 5, 5);
    }
}

EDIT 1:
Bad description of what I want to do :( Of course, the information is not relevant for me when designing the control, but for me (and others) when I put that control on a form or panel and want to use it.
EDIT 2:
Updated code, merged text-generation and painting code to a single condition. Added constructor. Still not working as intended (paints "runtime") when the user control is added to another user control in visual studio.

It should work when designing the user control. When you meant you are designing a form where coincidentally the user control is on then no the DesignMode of the form will be true as you are designing that and not the user control.

In case you might want to ask the LicenseManager about this

Well, i've tried both LicenseManager.UsageMode and LicenseManager.CurrentContext.UsageMode in the OnPaint method without success. So I decided to paint the value of LicenseManager.UsageMode directly without any conditions and it paints Runtime when I drop my UserControl (with the overriden OnPait method) on another UserControl...? I'm probably using the LicenseManager the wrong way, am I?

Why are you splitting the logic among two if-statements? if (LicenseManager.UsageMode == LicenseUsageMode.Designtime) { string msg = "test"; e.Graphics.DrawString(msg, Font, Brushes.Red, 10, 10); }

I think LicenseManager only works in the constructor. So store what you want to know from LicenseManager in the constructor and then use that stored knowledge in OnPaint.

Test DesignMode when the Site of the Component has already been generated

@Ralf Tried what you suggested (and updated the code in my post), but without luck :(

Hmh. Should work. Take a look at the options discussed here

@Ralf Thanks for the link, the method created there IsDesignerHosted works and I've created an extension method from it so I can use it where I need it. Thanks
